# Iptables (port forwarding from vps openvpn server to vpn client)

Tags: openvpn, vpn, pfsense, sip

I install openvpn server in Centos VPS. I can connect from my pfsense router. I forwrad rdp a port to my local pc, but can not forward rtp port.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.19

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 10000:20000 -j DNAT --to 10.8.0.19
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -p udp -d 10.8.0.19 --dport 10000:20000 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

3389 is obviously not within 10000:20000 thus an additional statement is needed:

```
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -p udp -d 10.8.0.19 --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

make RELATED traffic ACCEPT'ed in FORWARD chain.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

The second rule is not necessary in this case, but can help other traffics.